# Reduce space below radio checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with radio boxes on a dev website.
In a contact form I have 4 radio buttons which can be selected. Issue is that the boxes and text are not aligned properly.
[falsly aligned radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SQ27.png)

The radio boxes should not have that much space below. Right now it looks like the are aligned to the top, but should rather be aligned to the middle so they are on one height with the text. Hope you know what I mean.

I tried adding minus margin to the bottom or adding margin to the top but this adds also space to the radio box text.
[after adding margin-top: 35px;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUoPT.png)

It should be aligned just like in the following screenshot. The small blue line should be in the middle of the radio box.
[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwKsr.png)

Comment: This isn't a question, and the screenshots don't give any tangible context. Please include [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

This strongly depends on your implementation, one can only guess for an answer without the code used.

A guess: you could set the height of the radio button to 1em.

Another guess that likely works but would not be nice code:

```css
transform: translateY(50%); /* on the radio buttons */
```